# How to compress separately with password hundreds of files in tar.gz?

Tags: bash, terminal, compression, gzip, tar

A folder may contain up to ~200 videos in mkv format.

How could I use bash to compress each video in a separate tar.gz file? So I don't have to do it manually for each file.

Comment: What have you tried? Usually you'd use a command to do it.

Comment: `tar.gz` format doesn't have any inherent password support. You'd have to show how you're trying to encrypt / password-protect the content to provide a useful answer.

Comment: BTW, `tar` is generally pointless if you just want one archive per input file -- it's an *archiver*; it doesn't do any part of the compression, but has the sole purpose to bundle multiple files together with metadata about their name/permissions/etc. Just `your-video.mkv.gz` makes more sense than `your-video.mkv.tar.gz` in that case.

Comment: Ok, after reading origins of tar files I see why it is pointless for single files. I did not know that tar does not support encryption. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tar does not have a password option.  You're probably better off using something like zip.  Here's an example shell script to process all of the files in the directory.

```
for i in *.mkv; do 
  zip --password "thepassword" "$i.zip" "$i" 
done
```

Comment: Thank you. Works seamlessly. And I can even adapt it to general files and folders.